# CSS - Overflow hidden breaks css triangle

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I'm not that good with css. My scenario:

i'm trying to use a css triangle on active list item.

```
<div class="bx-viewport"> <!-- this div has overflow:hidden for need. -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-noborder bxslider">
    <li> <!-- css triangle when the item is active -->
      ... <!-- some text -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

list css:

```
.nav-tabs-noborder > li.active:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #fff;
  content: '';
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  bottom: -22px;
}
```

div.bx-viewport css:

```
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

The triangle only works if i remove overflow hidden. But in this scenario i can't. Is there solution/workaround for that ?

PS: I'm using bxSlider.

Below the print for what i need and showing css properties. (Removing overflow hidden)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LpMG.png

Comment: And... there is no code.

Comment: Ready @Terry , Hashem Qolami

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav-tabs-noborder > li.active:after {
  content: '▼';
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  bottom: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

You can style the downward triangle using `font-size`, `color` etc. and position it correctly using `margins`.

Answer (score 0):

I use these rules to create a triangle. You could try:

```
.triangle{    
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 14px 7px 0 7px;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the problem is not the triangle, cause it shows if i remove overflow property on <div class="bx-viewport> . I need some workaround with overflow:hidden, that's how <ul> shows if i remove hidden: http://i.imgur.com/iOl8FiX.png

Comment: @victorkurauchi did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes @FahadHasan ! Didn't work for my purpose. I'm still trying ! But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get rid of `position: relative;` on div.bx-viewport, that should unhide your triangle. The `bottom: -22px;` will move it below the bottom of the viewport, though, so you'll have to scroll down to see it.